# Flip axis and coefficient points in coefficient plot with dwplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, coefficients

I'm using the function "dwplot" from the package "dotwhisker" in order to plot the regression coefficients from some LSDV models. This is my model:

```r
coefisubv <- lm(subv ~ Preelectoral + Electoral + Postelectoral + 
                factor(ccaa)-1, data = datos)
```

Then I converted it into a dataframe so I can delete the factor(ccaa)-1 variables that I don't need:

```r
coefisubv <- as.data.frame(coefisubv)
```

After that, I want to flip the order of the axis, so I use the function coord_flip(). Then I also want to change the order of the variables in the X axis with the command vars_order().

```r
dwplot(coefisubv, 
       vars_order = c("Postelectoral", "Electoral", "Preelectoral")) + 
    coord_flip()
```

Finally, I want to add a line that links the coefficient points in the plot using geom_line()

```r
dwplot(coefisubv, 
       vars_order = c("Postelectoral", "Electoral", "Preelectoral")) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_line(aes(Estimate, term), group=1)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Unfortunately, as you can see, it seems the geom_line() function doesn't recognize that the order of the variables changed, so it believes the variable "Preelectoral" is the variable "Postelectoral" and "Postelectoral" is "Preelectoral".
How can I fix this?

Comment: What if you did this before making the plot: `coefisubv$term <- factor(as.character(coefisubv$term), levels=c("Preelectoral", "Electoral", "Postelectoral"))`, it changes the ordering of the factor `term` and then you should be able to not change the variable order and the line should print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I generally find it easier to use `broom::tidy` + `ggplot2` to build coefficient plots by hand when I want to do something a little bit complicated.  In this case, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp  + disp + drat + factor(cyl) - 1, mtcars)
tt <- (tidy(m1, conf.int = TRUE) 
     ## drop unwanted terms
     %>% filter(!stringr::str_detect(term, "cyl"))
     ## determine term ordering (alphabetical is default)
     %>% mutate(across(term, ~ factor(., levels = c("hp", "disp", "drat"))))
)
gg1 <- (ggplot(tt)
   +  aes(x=term, y=estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)
   +  geom_pointrange(colour = "red")
   +  geom_line(aes(group = 1))
)
```

- no need to use `coord_flip()` because we set the plot up with the orientation you wanted in the first place
- `aes(group = 1)` in `geom_line()` makes sure we're connecting points even though the x-axis variable is  a factor
- if you want to use this for a plot with multiple models, `purrr::map_dfr` is great (name your list of models and use `.id = "model"`)
- you can use `dotwhisker::by_2sd` if you need to standardize coefficients